# Can you create more than one of the same-colored grape at harvest?

Tags: viticulture

Say you already have a level 3 red grape. Can you harvest a field that has a 2-red-vine, and a 1-red-vine, and create a 1-grape and a 2-grape from it, as one harvest action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you could not create two red tokens from one harvest action.  From the rules [here](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/9f/c0/a5-viticulture-essential-edition-rulebook.pdf) you create up to one white and one red tokens on the crush pad.

> To harvest a field, add the total value of all red grape icons on the
> vine to create 1 red grape token and then add the total value of all
> white grape icons on the vine to create 1 white grape token on your
> crush pad.

The rules are specific it is "1" and not 2 in smaller combinations.

In your situation you must try to create a value 3 red grape token and then devalue it.

> If the grape icon already has a token on it when you harvest a grape
> at that value, you must devalue the grape token to the next available
> lowest icon.

In your example you would place a red token on the number 2 space.

Comment: Well, I guess it makes as much sense as “grapes aging”. ‍♂️